# LinkButton Click event ignored

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback, linkbutton

I have the following Hyperlink as a button:-

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="loginButton" runat="server" CssClass="loginButton" Text="LOGIN" OnClientClick="return validateLogin(memNoID,pwID)" AddressOf="loginButton.Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

It causes a postback but only executes the onload and prerender sections of code. It totally ignores the following function signature:-

```
Protected Sub loginButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Some code

End Sub
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: did you try onClick event for the button?

Answer (score 2):

Add OnClick in your code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="loginButton" runat="server" CssClass="loginButton" Text="LOGIN" OnClientClick="return validateLogin(memNoID,pwID)" OnClick="loginButton_Click" AddressOf="loginButton.Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Though don't know why. Googled this to death and nowhere did it mention both AddressOf AND OnClick.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding your _Click method to the OnClick event?